# GQL SELECT Sorting

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql

is there any easier way to select & sort **by weight** ?

```
fetchCount = 1000
date1 = datetime.datetime.utcnow().date() 
entries = GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Entry WHERE category = :category and date >= :datetime ORDER BY date, weight DESC", category = category, datetime = date1).fetch(fetchCount)

if entries is not None:
    # Sort entries ( lazy way for now ).
    sort = True
    while sort:
        sort = False
        for i in range(0, len(entries)-1):
            if entries[i].weight < entries[i + 1].weight:
                e = entries[i + 1]
                entries[i + 1] = entries[i]
                entries[i] = e
                sort = True
```

Comment: What is difficult about the current way?

Comment: because I don't want to sort it each time like that, I want to do it with query itself if that's possible.

Comment: I don't understand the problem, does the first query don't work?

Comment: Yes first query works, but it ONLY orders by date, and not by weight at all.... I need them sorted by weight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solved by:

```
entries = GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Entry WHERE category = :category and date > :datetime ORDER BY date, weight DESC", category = category, datetime = date1).fetch(fetchCount)
entries = sorted(entries, key=lambda x: x.weight, reverse=True)
```

since there is no other way atm....

Answer (score 1):

It's a limitation of the datastore that if you use an inequality filter (e.g. date >= :datetime) that must also be your first ordering key. Also, you can only have inequalities on one property per query.  So, in your case you have no choice but sorting them in memory.  The sorted() call in the other answer is perfect.